# Injection of touch events using screen driver

Tags: java, android, linux-device-driver

Using [android-event-injector](http://code.google.com/p/android-event-injector/) library, I wrote an application to inject a touch event when some event is triggered. The problem is that i need to inject touch at absolute coordinates of a given `View`, so I do the following to get the location on screen:

```
View v = /* find view*/;
int [] coords = new int[2];
v.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
```

This gives me the absolute coordinates on screen. The problem is that touch injection doesn't work.

I can inject correctly touches in screen driver, but for some reason the coordinates are misunderstood and touches are injected elsewhere.
Here are some examples (my screen is 1024x600 landscape oriented):

- Coords (0,0) -> Injected in (0,0)
- Coords (0,600) -> Injected in (0,351)
- Coords (1024,0) -> Not injected (most likely x is out of range)
- Coords (1024,600) -> Not injected (most likely x is out of range)
- Coords (640,480) -> Not injected (most likely x is out of range)
- Coords (512,300) -> Injected in (872,175)
- Coords (100,100) -> Injected in (170,58)

Comment: When you try injecting touch events into the screen driver, maybe you are overlooking the screen calibration (magnitude and/or axes) which is resulting in your touch events being understood, but at the wrong on-screen co-ordinates. Enable display of pointer x,y co-ordinates in developer-options in Android settings and update your question with a few pairs of values-injected in driver and values detected on-screen(ideally anywhere in the four corners of your display).

Comment: @TheCodeArtist I tried and added some examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the sample values it appears that the

1. Touchscreen is (600, 1024),
2. Mapped to a (1024,600) display.

To generate a touch event at (X,Y)display co-ordinates, the (x,y)touch co-ordinates that need to be injected can be calculated as follows

```
x(touch) = (600/1024) * X(disp)
y(touch) = (1024/600) * Y(disp)
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the display dimensions (2.) ? I mean you can get the touchscreen ones (1.) by using DisplayMetrics but how can you get the display ones programmatic?