# AccessibilityService: Is possible draw password on remote smartphone screen with mouse?

Tags: android, delphi, coordinates, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I'm working in a project similar to [Team View QuickSupport](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market&hl=pt_BR) and i want know if [`AccessibilityService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) allow perform a swipe on a remote screen that can be able to draw the password that protect device?

[image]

I comes trying the following code, but without success. Until now all that happens is a exception on android code that says:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Attempting to add too many strokes to a gesture**

here:

```
gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0, time));
```

The current Java code is this:

```
    if (xline.contains("mouseswipescreen")) {

     String coords = xline.replace("mouseswipescreen", "");

     String[] tokens = coords.split(Pattern.quote("<|>"));

               float x = parseFloat(tokens[0]);
               float y = parseFloat(tokens[1]);
               String cmd = tokens[2];

     MyAccessibility.instance.Swipte((int) x, (int) y, 50, cmd);
 }
```

---

```
GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder;
Path path;

public void Swipte(int x, int y, int time, String command) {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        System.out.println(" ======= Swipte =======");

        if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("start")) {

            gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
            path = new Path();

            path.moveTo(x, y);

        } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("move")) {

            path.lineTo(x, y);
            gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0, time));

        } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("dispatch")) {

            dispatchGesture(gestureBuilder.build(), new GestureResultCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                    System.out.println("SWIPTE Gesture Completed :D");
                    super.onCompleted(gestureDescription);
                }
            }, null);
        }
    }

}
```

Now changing this code to perform a swipe screen that stays this way:

```
public void Swipte(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int time){

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

            System.out.println(" ======= Swipte =======");

            GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
            Path path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(x1,y1); // "mousedown"
            path.lineTo(x2,y2); // until last position found in "mousemove"

            gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0, time));
            dispatchGesture(gestureBuilder.build(), new GestureResultCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                    System.out.println("SWIPTE Gesture Completed :D");
                    super.onCompleted(gestureDescription);
                }
            }, null);
        }

    }
```

The result is this:

[image]

See that is drawn a wrong password.

Lastly follows the code (Delphi) that send the coordenates ([*reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17976508/9672569)) based in first Java code above:

```
 private
    { Private declarations }
    fDown: Boolean;
    fPO: TPoint;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  ...

procedure TForm2.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  Index, XTouch, YTouch, RXCoord, RYCoord: Integer;
  List: TStrings;
  RScreen, Start: String;
begin
  Index := Form1.ListView1.ItemIndex;
  if Index = -1 then
    Exit;

    List := TStringList.Create;
    RScreen := Form1.ListView1.Selected.SubItems[6]; // Remote screen resolution

    try
      ExtractStrings(['x'], [], PChar(RScreen), List); // Ex: my smartphone is 1920x1080
      RYCoord := StrToInt(List[0]);                    // 1920 (height)
      RXCoord := StrToInt(List[1]);                    // 1080 (width)
    finally
      List.Free;
    end;

    XTouch := Round((X / Image1.Width) * RXCoord);
    YTouch := Round((Y / Image1.Height) * RYCoord);

    fPO := Point(XTouch, YTouch);
    Start := 'start';
    fDown := true;

    Form1.ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[Index].SendText(format('mouseswipescreen%d<|>%d<|>%s'#13#10, [fPO.X, fPO.Y, Start]));

  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
var
  Index, XTouch, YTouch, RXCoord, RYCoord: Integer;
  List: TStrings;
  RScreen, Move: String;
begin

  Index := Form1.ListView1.ItemIndex;
  if Index = -1 then
    Exit;

  List := TStringList.Create;
  RScreen := Form1.ListView1.Selected.SubItems[6]; // Remote screen resolution

  try
    ExtractStrings(['x'], [], PChar(RScreen), List); // Ex: my smartphone is 1920x1080
    RYCoord := StrToInt(List[0]);                    // 1920 (height)
    RXCoord := StrToInt(List[1]);                    // 1080 (width)
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;

  XTouch := Round((X / Image1.Width) * RXCoord);
  YTouch := Round((Y / Image1.Height) * RYCoord);

  if fDown then
  begin

    Move := 'move';

    Form1.ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[Index].SendText(format('mouseswipescreen%d<|>%d<|>%s'#13#10, [fPO.X, fPO.Y, Move]));

    fPO := Point(XTouch, YTouch);

  end;

end;

procedure TForm2.Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if fDown then
    fDown := false;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, i answer my own question, already that the experts in `AccessibilityService` think that i'm building a malware and not like of help these kind of people.

---

**ANSWER:**

My approach above is right and unfortunately until this moment was saw that, not is possible achieve this goal using `AccessibilityService`, because exists [limitation on storage of gestures](https://gitlab.com/TeeFirefly/FireNow-Nougat/blob/e25808459b8dec3013caebb7391871f235b5fffa/cts/tests/accessibilityservice/src/android/accessibilityservice/cts/GestureDescriptionTest.java#L118), [**here**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/GestureDescription.Builder#addStroke(android.accessibilityservice.GestureDescription.StrokeDescription)) is the official reference:

```
addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0, time));
```

And also, until now (in this case) `AccessibilityService` not is able to perform a gesture of touch "**only press and not loose**" in some point (of 9 points that compose the password screen) when 2 fast mouse clicks are perform and sent on:

```
procedure TForm2.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
```

before start and during drawing the password (dragging mouse), and release only when password be drawn completely and:

```
procedure TForm2.Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
```

be sent to remote device.

---

**EDIT:**

**Note:** *[Team View QuickSupport](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market&hl=pt_BR) is able to this because use [**code of root gave to he by several vendors**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20391295/9672569).*